# How to Close SQLite Cursor and other open SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to write a code in Android and going through following errors. I am opening a SQLite database and using Cursor.

**Java Code**

```
              for(int y3=0;y3<10;y3++)
              {


                        String sql_query5= "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Id="+y3+"";

                        Cursor cur5 = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE).rawQuery(sql_query5, null);

                        if(cur5.moveToNext())
                        {

                            //

                        }}
```

So i need to display the Age in the layout but i am facing **SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException** and Database object not closed. I don't understand the errors.

Please let me know some solution and suggestion !!!

Comment: Close the cursor like this : " curb.close(); ", after you're done with it. Same goes for the Database object. " db.close(); " If you're using loop, close these objects only after loop's finished.

Comment: Yes , i was also thinking that in this way and now i am editing my question please go through it...

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use hard-coded file paths. You have no guarantees about the structure of the filesystem.
2. Learn to use [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). This is what helps you create and maintain your SQLite database. Instead of trying to open the database yourself, you create a `new SQLiteOpenHelper` and call `getReadableDatabase()`.
3. When you are done reading from a Cursor, call `cursor.close()`.
4. If you want to close the database, you can call `close()` on it as well; just be aware that any cursors you got by querying it will no longer be able to give you data, so make sure you are finished them those before closing the database.

Answer (score 0):

add '' in your

```
String sql_query5= "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Id='"+y3+"' ";
```